# Python pip troubleshooting, cannot install packages. VsCode on aws Workspace

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install packages on Python that is on an AWS Workspace (windows instance) and I'm interacting with using VS Code. I am able to run python commands using base packages in Jupyter notebook but I'm unable to run anything from the command prompt or PowerShell related to Python or pip. For Python commands I get the error "No installed Python found!"

My interpreter is installed on the C drive. VScode is installed on the C drive. Python commands run in Jupyter notebook using base packages with the C python interpreter utilized.

My issue is anything using command prompt or PowerShell does not recognize python or pip, even when being in the C directory.

Not sure where the disconnect is. Any additional troubleshooting would be appreciated.

VSCODE settings have the C interpreter as the default.

Comment: Have you added the folder where Python is installed to PATH? If you haven't, you need to do that and restart the machine and then it should work.